# Increase div's height above browser resolution with percentage

Tags: html, css, resolution

I have the following css:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
}
#div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
#div2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
#div3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Let's say my browser resolution is 1280 width and 768 height.Container div's height is 100% of my viewport.And the sum of the 3 div's is also 100%.At this moment i have no vertical scrollbar,because the content doesn't exceed the viewport.

If i add some content inside ,the child divs will push each other and so a vertical scrollbar will show up because the total height of the content exceeds the viewport ( 768px height ).But the child divs also overlapps parent div,because it's set to be 100% of the browser size.

I need to find a way,to keep the container at 100% height of the viewport.Logically it should change it's size once with the viewport because it's set with dynamic measurements,but it doesn't.The container have 768px , but now ,because the content is bigger, the viewport value is another ( as an exampple: 900px height ) .

Comment: @How about using min-height declarations instead?

Comment: @jbutler483 , for child divs or for the parent div?

Comment: Child. But It's only from my understanding of what you're looking for. Maybe include a snippet of 'what it's actually doing' might help. (As you've said yourself, it's hard to explain). I would also tend to use vh and vw units for this sort of thing. But that's just me ;)

Comment: Well vh it's no use here because container is 100% height of browser.And it's exactly the same if i set 20% for div1 or 20vh.

Comment: What do you mean by "the content will overlap the div"?

Comment: I am also having a hard time understanding exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "But the child divs also overlapps parent div"? That's typically what child divs do... You need to be more specific about what you want to happen. If you want the container to be 100% of the viewport, what do you want to happen if the content is longer than the space available for it? Should it clip it? Should it dynamically adjust the height of the other child divs to make room for it if possible? Should it make the text size smaller? Be specific and you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand corectly,don't set any height value for the child divs.They should expand once the content grow,or you can just give a condition like a min-height.Also i suggest you to use vh,but only for the container.And if you want,you can set a width,i dont think it will cause any trouble,but keep it in mind that the divs will automatically have the full width of the parent div.

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#div1 {
    width: 100%;
}
#div2 {
    width: 100%;
}
#div3 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The code above will make your container be 100% height of the viewport,and if your content it's bigger,the child divs will push each other and container div will be 100% height of the new viewport.

Answer (score 1):

[Viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) should do the trick.

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: red;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: blue;
}
#div3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  background: orange;
}
#div4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: lime;
}
```

See a working example at [Codepen](http://codepen.io/zeitwidrig/pen/NPmomX). Overall [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I am understanding your problem correctly.

As far as I've done it, your problem is that you have your container heights defined with percentages (to allow them to refit correctly on different screen resolutions) but, when your content grows in a container it overlaps with the containers that you have below.

Well... first of all, if you want to avoid your content to making grow your containers you should use overflow:auto, not overflow:hidden. This should add scrollbars automatically to your container when it's content occupies more space than it has.

Keep in mind that content is more important than design, so if your content is greater than the space that you reserves to it, by default browsers will fit your containers to the required space.

The strange thing here is that below containers should be pushed downwards by the growing one, not get overlapped by it. This makes me think that maybe there's some more code interfering with the simple example you show us?

Comment: Let me explain it again,i have a container with 100%(of 768px browser height) height,and 3 div's with 20%,20%,60% .Let's say those div's are empty.In this case the div's will fully ocuppy the entire height page which is 768px at this moment.If i add some content that exceeds child divs height,they should push each other and grow the total height of the browser.Now the browser should have a new height(and the browser vertical scollbar will show up) of (as an example) 900px.So the container now will have 100% height of 900px(the new value).

Comment: That's what logically should happen,but in my case the child divs overlaps each other and the total height of the browser don't grow,obviously the vertical scrollbar won't show up show up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my end, I am not sure if this what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addText").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().append("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a pag")
  });
});
```

```css
       html,
       body {
         height: 100%;
         min-height: 100%;
       }
       #container div {
         overflow-y: auto;
         position: relative;
       }
       #container {
         width: 100%;
         /*min-height: 100%;*/
         height: auto;
       }
       #div1 {
         background: green;
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 20vh;
       }
       #div2 {
         background: blue;
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 20vh;
       }
       #div3 {
         background: red;
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 60vh;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="div1">

    <button id="addText">Add TEXT</button>

  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing

  </div>

  <div id="div3"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-height instead of height on the divs, and also remove width on the divs:

```
#div1{ min-height: 20% }
#div2{ min-height: 20% }
#div3{ min-height: 60% }
```

Width is removed since divs are block elements by default, and block elements will take the full available width.

Block elements will also tend to "push" content down. In your example you have restricted this push effect by setting the width property, which tells the browser to never grow that element bigger than x% of the screen size.

By setting the min-width on an element you are basically telling the browser that if there is more content then grow the element to accommodate the content.

Another thing to check for is the "box-sizing" property. When you tell the browser to use 40% width on an element, do you want to include the padding and margin of that element in the 40%? If so:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

Comment: i need to set a width,because the container has to be 80% width of browser width.Also i've set a max-width and min-width for container because i need it to be the same on every resolution.

Comment: I was answering the question  "child divs overlapping each other". Test to see if setting just min-height on the said divs will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED to add flexbox prefixes for browser support**

`flexbox` makes this dead simple.

Add as much content as you wish and the layout will never break.

```css
* { 
  margin:0; padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html,body { 
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; 
}

#container { 
  height:100%;
 -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 }

#div1 {
  background: red;
 -webkit-flex: 1 0 20%;
 -moz-flex: 1 0 20%;
 -ms-flex: 1 0 20%;
 flex: 1 0 20%;
}
#div2 {
  background: blue;
 -webkit-flex: 1 0 20%;
 -moz-flex: 1 0 20%;
 -ms-flex: 1 0 20%;
 flex: 1 0 20%;
}
#div3 {
  background: orange;
 -webkit-flex: 1 0 60%;
 -moz-flex: 1 0 60%;
 -ms-flex: 1 0 60%;
 flex: 1 0 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
   <div id="div3"></div>
</div><!-- #container --->
```

Comment: @jbutler483 - Flexbox support is in IE10+ and all other modern browsers (albeit with prefixes that I haven't shown). Flexbox does have browser-specific bugs....er, nuances (remember when we had those even with floats?) but the above layout works in all the browsers that support flexbox. Also worth nothing that IE8/9 market share is not increasing, but decreasing (both browsers combined total about 6% of global market share right now). And finally, I've been using flexbox in production sites (I've built about 20 or so) for about 8 months now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use viewport units ... you shouldn't specify the height though, or your content could extend beyond the container into the next - use minimum heights instead ...

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20vh;
  background: red;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20vh;
  background: yellow;
}
#div3 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Example with content:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20vh;
  background: red;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20vh;
  background: yellow;
}
#div3 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  background: green;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Benchmark compelling customized, "enhance revolutionize drive, bleeding-edge revolutionize world-class," peer-to-peer, revolutionize visualize aggregate. Strategize engage paradigms; interfaces, relationships monetize partnerships deliver envisioneer one-to-one wireless niches ecologies content data-driven harness engage strategize authentic frictionless, web-enabled; viral. Channels communities repurpose disintermediate incubate enhance webservices granular: envisioneer reintermediate open-source beta-test harness iterate blogging: ubiquitous morph widgets. Life-hacks; synergies metrics peer-to-peer, B2C turn-key relationships dynamic supply-chains, virtual schemas." Visualize one-to-one B2C integrateAJAX-enabled infrastructures empower networking synergies deliver dot-com enable seize disintermediate, viral drive blogging open-source. Wireless enhance magnetic sticky. Design envisioneer end-to-end: empower content embrace innovative bricks-and-clicks communities grow, action-items benchmark holistic holistic, "markets open-source; dot-com e-business revolutionary." Niches incubate niches plug-and-play methodologies web-readiness, end-to-end extend utilize mission-critical ubiquitous web services. Repurpose convergence generate transition morph matrix: initiatives real-time supply-chains web services benchmark users, innovate innovative global architectures technologies systems, deliver. Interactive Cluetrain relationships Cluetrain transparent interactive scale deliverables. Mindshare infomediaries generate interactive, reinvent platforms transparent enhance citizen-media, markets web-readiness clicks-and-mortar frictionless. Plug-and-play compelling generate channels synergies seamless integrate next-generation scale monetize integrateAJAX-enabled empower: data-driven; partnerships action-items. Utilize semantic leverage rich-clientAPIs user-centric transform, "cross-platform dot-com, communities incentivize intuitive, design real-time implement enhance harness applications global?" Communities, integrate expedite interactive whiteboard ubiquitous e-services leading-edge dynamic metrics 24/365, deliver seize vertical, blogging e-business one-to-one; magnetic deliverables beta-test capture user-centric bandwidth optimize. B2C deliver B2B efficient Cluetrain A-list technologies, design podcasts tag orchestrate syndicate cross-platform enable, initiatives mindshare one-to-one viral partnerships interfaces.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Benchmark compelling customized, "enhance revolutionize drive, bleeding-edge revolutionize world-class," peer-to-peer, revolutionize visualize aggregate. Strategize engage paradigms; interfaces, relationships monetize partnerships deliver envisioneer one-to-one wireless niches ecologies content data-driven harness engage strategize authentic frictionless, web-enabled; viral. Channels communities repurpose disintermediate incubate enhance webservices granular: envisioneer reintermediate open-source beta-test harness iterate blogging: ubiquitous morph widgets. Life-hacks; synergies metrics peer-to-peer, B2C turn-key relationships dynamic supply-chains, virtual schemas." Visualize one-to-one B2C integrateAJAX-enabled infrastructures empower networking synergies deliver dot-com enable seize disintermediate, viral drive blogging open-source. Wireless enhance magnetic sticky. Design envisioneer end-to-end: empower content embrace innovative bricks-and-clicks communities grow, action-items benchmark holistic holistic, "markets open-source; dot-com e-business revolutionary." Niches incubate niches plug-and-play methodologies web-readiness, end-to-end extend utilize mission-critical ubiquitous web services. Repurpose convergence generate transition morph matrix: initiatives real-time supply-chains web services benchmark users, innovate innovative global architectures technologies systems, deliver. Interactive Cluetrain relationships Cluetrain transparent interactive scale deliverables. Mindshare infomediaries generate interactive, reinvent platforms transparent enhance citizen-media, markets web-readiness clicks-and-mortar frictionless. Plug-and-play compelling generate channels synergies seamless integrate next-generation scale monetize integrateAJAX-enabled empower: data-driven; partnerships action-items. Utilize semantic leverage rich-clientAPIs user-centric transform, "cross-platform dot-com, communities incentivize intuitive, design real-time implement enhance harness applications global?" Communities, integrate expedite interactive whiteboard ubiquitous e-services leading-edge dynamic metrics 24/365, deliver seize vertical, blogging e-business one-to-one; magnetic deliverables beta-test capture user-centric bandwidth optimize. B2C deliver B2B efficient Cluetrain A-list technologies, design podcasts tag orchestrate syndicate cross-platform enable, initiatives mindshare one-to-one viral partnerships interfaces.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <p>Benchmark compelling customized, "enhance revolutionize drive, bleeding-edge revolutionize world-class," peer-to-peer, revolutionize visualize aggregate. Strategize engage paradigms; interfaces, relationships monetize partnerships deliver envisioneer one-to-one wireless niches ecologies content data-driven harness engage strategize authentic frictionless, web-enabled; viral. Channels communities repurpose disintermediate incubate enhance webservices granular: envisioneer reintermediate open-source beta-test harness iterate blogging: ubiquitous morph widgets. Life-hacks; synergies metrics peer-to-peer, B2C turn-key relationships dynamic supply-chains, virtual schemas." Visualize one-to-one B2C integrateAJAX-enabled infrastructures empower networking synergies deliver dot-com enable seize disintermediate, viral drive blogging open-source. Wireless enhance magnetic sticky. Design envisioneer end-to-end: empower content embrace innovative bricks-and-clicks communities grow, action-items benchmark holistic holistic, "markets open-source; dot-com e-business revolutionary." Niches incubate niches plug-and-play methodologies web-readiness, end-to-end extend utilize mission-critical ubiquitous web services. Repurpose convergence generate transition morph matrix: initiatives real-time supply-chains web services benchmark users, innovate innovative global architectures technologies systems, deliver. Interactive Cluetrain relationships Cluetrain transparent interactive scale deliverables. Mindshare infomediaries generate interactive, reinvent platforms transparent enhance citizen-media, markets web-readiness clicks-and-mortar frictionless. Plug-and-play compelling generate channels synergies seamless integrate next-generation scale monetize integrateAJAX-enabled empower: data-driven; partnerships action-items. Utilize semantic leverage rich-clientAPIs user-centric transform, "cross-platform dot-com, communities incentivize intuitive, design real-time implement enhance harness applications global?" Communities, integrate expedite interactive whiteboard ubiquitous e-services leading-edge dynamic metrics 24/365, deliver seize vertical, blogging e-business one-to-one; magnetic deliverables beta-test capture user-centric bandwidth optimize. B2C deliver B2B efficient Cluetrain A-list technologies, design podcasts tag orchestrate syndicate cross-platform enable, initiatives mindshare one-to-one viral partnerships interfaces.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> overflow : auto;

try this

```
#div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```